# Logger (log4j) не пишет в log

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, сервлеты, log4j2

Есть простое web-приложение на Java с использованием Tomcat.

Вот код сервлета.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("method started");
        //............
    }
}
```

При выполнении метода `processRequest()` ничего не пишется в log file.

Зависимости в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Вот файл `log4j2.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <File name = "file" filename = "web/WEB-INF/log.log" append = "true">
            <PatternLayout pattern = "%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %t %C{1}:%M - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Async name = "appender" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref = "file"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="appender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

P.S. Тут в лог пишет все прекрасно. `Test` в том же  пакете, что и `Controller`

```
public class Test {
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("kjadgadjs");
        while (true) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для томката другая конфигурация логера, по моему.
Напиши в гугле: how to configure log4j in tomcat

Comment: Как решили вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Надо указывать параметр класса при инициализации логгера. Вот например

```
public static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Controller.class);
```

У вас неверная версия имплементации для фреймворка лога log4j, используйте

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

И у вас неверная конфигурация логгера, который не может создавать файлы в `WEB-INF`. Поменяйте путь к файлу, используйте URL.

Comment: Я пробовал Ваш совет - не помогает.

Comment: @Jake *не помогает* - это не значит, что ответ неверный